# Global Keyboard hook in windows does not work on firefox browser

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hook, keyboard-hook

My global keyboard hook on windows does not work on the Firefox browser. If I press a key on other system its working but on certain application like Firefox browser, task manager it does not work.

Is there any security privilege are required?

Comment: Please check with ProcessExplorer is your hook library ever loaded in the FireFox address space?

Comment: thank you @Ari0nhh , So you are saying that even the global hook also needs to load dll into the firefox address space.

Comment: Of course. Please read this article for the additional info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037/Hooks-and-DLLs